# How can I run Selenium tests when my site is in Vagrant?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, vagrant

I use Vagrant for my local development. Now I want to use Selenium for automated browser testing. When I setup Selenium in my VM, it works like a charm (great stuff by the way).

But now I want to move the Selenium testing out of the box. I tried to run the Java server on my host machine, forward port 4444 to port 4444 in virtualbox, and then fire the phpunit-command in VirtualBox, hoping to trigger the server on my host machine.

But instead I get a CURL-message that phpunit can't connect to `127.0.0.1:4444`, so obviously there is no connection to my host machine on this port.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** I figured out that when I'm running the server on the host, I cannot access `127.0.0.1:4444` in my browser, however, I am able to access `localhost:4444`. Which is weird, because my hosts-file has the correct line (although it shouldn't matter since phpunit is trying to access a numeric address).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for this is to setup a "private network" this way you'll be able to use internal address to access your vm and host separately...

Depending of your vm provider different solution are possible (for example, Virtualbox support internal netowrk only)

Have a look at : http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html

Comment: Where do you setup phpunit to test on the vagrant box and not on local?

Comment: This is somewhat a totally different question... One of the easiest way is to use ssh to launch phpunit remotely?

Comment: The problem comes to light when I want to use the Magento Testing Framework (MTF) (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_environment.html). It needs to run phpunit inside the Vagrant box (guest), but my selenium server is running on my host machine.